# Avoid rerender of component when updating Map in useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How do I fill a Map in useState without triggering a rerender of the React component?

`const [myMap, setMyMap] = useState(new Map());`

I'm placing key-values in there but experiencing that the **component is being re-rendered each time when using either**

```js
const insertToMap = (myMap, setMyMap, k, v) => {
myMap[k] = v;
  setMyMap(myMap);
}
```

**or**

```js
const insertToMap = (myMap, setMyMap, k, v) => {
myMap[k] = v;
  setMyMap(myMap.set(k, v));
}
```

How do I fill the map without causing a re-render?

Comment: How is the map being used? It seems a bit odd to have state that doesn't affect render

Comment: Good point. The keys in the map are ID's for checkbox elements, and the values are booleans (if they are checked or not). So, I want the `checked`-prop of each checkbox to be rendered correctly according to the Map on a re-render (the css depends on the checked status). If that makes sense. Maybe I should fill the map in one go?

Comment: If the Map values correspond to what gets rendered, then shouldn't a value change *result* in a re-render? It sounds very strange that you'd want to avoid a re-render when what sounds like an important stateful variable (that maps to what gets rendered) changes

Comment: True. I am a little confused over the setup I think. My first thought was to fill the Map without triggering re-renders, then only trigger re-renders when a checkbox was clicked onwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the map isn't considered at all when rendering, then you can mutate it instead - and, in such a case, it'd make more sense to use a ref than state:

```
const myMapRef = useRef(new Map());
// reference myMapRef.current to get to the map
```

But also note that if you want to use a Map as a Map, you should use the Map methods `.set`, `.get`, and `.has`:

```
const insertToMap = (myMap, k, v) => {
  myMap.set(k, v);
};
```

If you want to use bracket notation to store values, you should almost certainly be using an ordinary object instead, eg

```
const myObjRef = useRef({});
myObjRef[k] = v;
```

---

That's if you really want a change in the values not to result in a re-render. But given that

> I want the checked-prop of each checkbox to be rendered correctly according to the Map on a re-render

it sounds like this *really should* be stateful - you should almost certainly *want* a change in a value to result in a checkbox immediately being checked or unchecked (via a state change and resulting re-render).

It's good for stateful values to be able to be cloned easily so that setting their state (without mutating the object currently in state) isn't too tedious. Consider using an object instead of a Map, and:

```
const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState({});
const insert = (k, v) => {
  setCheckboxes({ ...checkboxes, [k]: v });
};
```

If this function gets called multiple times before a state update, use the callback form instead:

```
setCheckboxes(checkboxes => ({ ...checkboxes, [k]: v }));
```

> My first thought was to fill the Map without triggering re-renders

If all the initial setters occur synchronously, it shouldn't be something to worry about. You could also populate it before calling this component, and pass the populated object down as a prop.